# getaddrinfo: Name or service not known with solr sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, solr, sunspot-rails

I'm attempting to run solr and sunspot with rails 3.1, but I keep getting the error

```
getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
```

my controller is fairly basic

```
  def index
        @food_names = FoodName.search do 
            keywords(params[:term])
        end
  end
```

I'm still not quite sure about what is going on here. do I have to start a separate solr service?

When I run rake sunspot:solr:run, I get a

```
WARNING: 'require 'rake/rdoctask'' is deprecated.  Please use 'require 'rdoc/task' (in RDoc 2.4.2+)' instead.
    at /home/pete/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rdoctask.rb
WARNING: Global access to Rake DSL methods is deprecated.  Please include
    ...  Rake::DSL into classes and modules which use the Rake DSL methods.
WARNING: DSL method Kitchon::Application#task called at /home/pete/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:214:in `initialize_tasks'
WARNING: 'task :t, arg, :needs => [deps]' is deprecated.  Please use 'task :t, [args] => [deps]' instead.
    at /home/pete/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/sunspot_rails-1.2.0/lib/sunspot/rails/tasks.rb:41:in `block in '
rake aborted!
Server is already running with PID 4012

Tasks: TOP => sunspot:solr:start
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

which is a bit disconcerting, but as the output says, the server is already running, so I think it is working.

Any suggestions on what I may be doing wrong, or how to fix this?

Comment: Open a console and check the value of `Sunspot.config.solr.url` — what is it? Can you get to that in your browser?

Comment: Also, you can try the latest release candidate for the impending 1.3.0 release to trim down the warning output. `gem 'sunspot_rails', '~>1.3.0.rc6'`